# How to solve this percentage question without equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Question - The total population of a village is 5000. The number of males and females increases by 10% and 15% respectively and consequently the population of the village becomes 5600. What was the number of males in the village?

Answer 1 :

M + F = 5000

11M/10 + 23/20F = 5600

or 22M/20 M + 23/20 F = 5600

now equation multiply by 23/20

23/20M + 23/20F = 5750

now taking the difference, it becomes.

M/20 = 150

or M = 3000

number of Males is 3000.

--------- now I am trying to solve this without the equations. here is my approach. Please tell me what is wrong in my concept.

First is the population is increasing from 5000 to 5600 i.e.

600/5000 * 100 i.e. 12% increase

M is increased by 10% and Female is increased by 15%. However, the average increase is 12%. Now, I am lost. what should I do? 600 is the increase.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to solve this without equations? Pretty sure this is one of the reasons we came up with basic algebra in the first place.

Comment: You could guess and check but as the above comment says I don't know why you wouldn't want to use algebra.

Comment: algebra hinders mental calculation in my opinion. It is a long way to solve the question. I want to solve the problems in head. Only way to solve the problems in head is to eradicate equations.

Comment: Solving equations in your head and keeping track of up to 3-4 equations isn't too hard. Trying to solve these without equations would probably take up even more time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

If the original population were all male, it would only go up by $500$, not $600$.  If it were all female, it would go up to $750$.  Since $600$ is closer to $500$ than it is to $750$, it stands to reason there are more males than females in the original population.

Looked at more closely, $600$ is $100$ from $500$ and $150$ from $750$.  Those two differences are in the ratio $2:3$.  That means the ratio of men to women is $3:2$.  (Remember, we already concluded there should be more men than women.)  It's now clear that the original population was $3000$ males and $2000$ females.  As a quick check, $10\%$ of $3000$ is $300$, and $15\%$ of $2000$ is $300$, which together give $600$.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, so feel free to comment this answer.

Let $x$ be the number of men. Beforehand, you know there are $5000-x$ women. Now, there's a 10% increase in men, 15% increase in women, and a total population increase from 5000 up to 5600:

$$1.10\cdot x+1.15\cdot(5000-x)=\frac{5600}{5000}$$

Solving for $x$, you have
$$(1.10-1.15)\cdot x=\frac{5600}{5000}-1.15\cdot5000=1.12\cdot5000-1.15\cdot5000$$
$$\Rightarrow -0.05\cdot x = -0.03\cdot5000$$
$$\Rightarrow \cdot x = \frac{0.03}{0.05}\cdot5000=3000$$

Comment: This is again by equation,and I am looking for answer without using equations.

Comment: I understood you wanted something without equation systems... You can do it as I say: the equation is a result of a train of thought. If you follow the same train of thought, you'll get to the right answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

WITHOUT EQUATION
Total population 5000 now 10 & 15 % of 5000 are 500& 750. Again excess population is 5600 - 5000 i.e 600.

Now simple linkup formula ie 500 - 600 & 750 - 600 soo ratio becomes 150 : 100 i.e 3:2 i.e M = 3 & W = 2

Soo 3/5 of 5000 is 3000.

Soo total men are 3000

Comment: What is the 'simple linkup formula' you refer to? Also, please use MathJax to format your answer. In particular, writing `$5000$` displays as $5000$ rather than 5000.